# Click to display none/block with conditionals

Tags: jquery, html, conditional-statements

I don't know why the else conditional isn't working, I have tried multiple methods.

```
if($('hiddendDiv').attr('style') === 'display:none') {
    $('buttonDiv').click(function() {
        $('hiddendDiv').attr('style',"display:block");
    }); 
} else {
    $('body').click(function(){
        $('hiddendDiv').attr('style',"display:none");
    });
}
```

`hiddendDiv` has `style="display:none"`

When I click the `buttonDiv`, the `hiddenDiv` gets `display: block`, and after that when I click anywhere on the page (to close `hiddenDiv`), the `hiddenDiv` doesn't get `display: none`.

I am trying to make a `<div>` that opens when I click a button, and closes when I click anywhere on the page.

Comment: I forgot to add it here,sorry. In my original code i've added it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`buttonDiv` and `hiddendDiv` (hopefully) aren’t tag names; if you have elements with those IDs, you’ll want to select them with a leading `#`. Also, don’t check or change visibility like that, please.

```
if ($('#hiddendDiv').is(':visible')) {
    $('body').click(function () {
        $('#hiddendDiv').hide();
    });
} else {
    $('#buttonDiv').click(function () {
        $('#hiddendDiv').show();
    });
}
```

And if you don’t re-run this code, it’s not going to change the handlers for you. I’d go for this:

```
$('body').click(function () {
    $('#hiddendDiv').hide();
});

$('#buttonDiv').click(function (e) {
    $('#hiddendDiv').show();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

i.e. hide `#hiddendDiv` whenever there’s a click anywhere, but stop that listener from activating and show `#hiddendDiv` when `#buttonDiv` is clicked.

Comment: @minitech♦, thanks! I won't check visibility like i did before :).

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('click', '#test', function () {
    if ($('#text').hasClass("disabled")) {
        $('#text').css("display", "none");
        $('#text').removeClass('disabled');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#text').css("display", "block");
        $('#text').addClass('disabled');
    }

});
```

Comment: Please also edit your answer to explain in english where the problem lies and how your code addresses it